# What would be the response of a small island nation if a former enormous aggressor suddenly went away

Tags: medieval, diplomacy

If a small isolated subtropical island with a fairly low level of government and medieval technology was threatened by a large aggressor with similar technology that wanted it to surrender or be destroyed, and left a ship docked outside the island, what would their response be when the ship suddenly left and did not come back?  Assume a low level of temporary rune-based magic (no teleporting, flying, enchanting, but low-level illusions and fireballs) and little to none outside communication (occasional trade schooners with nearby similar islands) previous to the aggressor coming.  The island previously had most of its men available to fight due to long ago wars with neighboring islands, but the men are merely trained as militia.

Would the island be likely to come back into contact with the aggressor (who has some islands about 100km away) at any point in the next fifty to a hundred years?

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation is really annoying.  If you don't like the question, please give a reason and a suggestion on how to improve it.  Don't just downvote it!

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think your question is opinion-based. How characters handle certain situations is off-topic on WorldBuilding. It completely depends on things like: How long was the aggressor there? What did the population of the subtropical island do in this time? What aggressive tactics did the aggressor use? What culture does the population have? Are they naturally aggressive? Are they peace-loving? What kind of religion do they have that could influence their behaviour in regards to an aggressor? ... All these things are in the hands of the author and cannot be answered.

Comment: I apologize, and did not intend to create an opinion-based question.  I was not concerned about individual characters, but whether the island my civilization was threatening would come back and kill us while we are in the middle of a civil war.  I was trying to find possible reasons for coming after us, or not, as well as other possibilities.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Normally a question is put on hold to allow the OP to edit his post without the risk of invalidating existing answers. Once it's on-topic it can reopened. We also have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta where you can post a question first to get feedback on the style, especially regarding "on-topic/ off-topic", before releasing it onto the main site.

Comment: This still seems rather broad.  They could respond by heaving a sigh of relief and saying, "Well, that's over."  In which case, no, they wouldn't encounter the aggressor again.  Or they could say, "Geez, that ship was neat.  Why don't we build one?"  In which case, they probably would.  Rather than asking us for options, pick one, describe it, and ask us if it is realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends on what was already done against the threat**

If quite nothing, the islanders might only sight in relief, and continue their lives as it was before the aggressor.

If they have strengthened their military capabilities by training warriors, hiring mercenaries or forging an alliance with nearby islands, they might decide to use their new power and start expansion. (Look at Delos Alliance after the Persian wars.) If not, inner tension might arise: warrior class losing its legitimation, mercenaries becoming unpaid, are always good reason for some civil war.

Another possibility is, that they become isolationist, and start to think, that any interference with the outside world would be harfmull to them.

EDIT: I don't think that they would soon get contact with the former aggressor. If they start to expand, they might conquer their neighbour islands, and eventually reach the waters of the aggressor. But you wrote that they have only one ship, and some semi-trained militia, so it's unlikely.

But if there were some among the islanders, who advocated surrendering to the aggressor, there is a chance, that after the aggressor is gone, they start to view them as traitors. If they send these people into exile, the outcasts may decide to seek out the aggressor, and ask for its help.

Comment: The part of the world I actually care about is the aggressor.  Would they be likely to come into contact with them again (eg. by exploration, as the aggressor now has its own problems which are beyond the scope of this question.  I don't care what they do if they don't go exploring and find the powerful (now less so) people again.

Comment: The islanders had sent their only ship (a small schooner) to a nearby island to ask for help.  It will come back with the message that none is forthcoming but only after the aggressor leaves.  They have started training warriors, and had already had some due to former wars with other tribes, but they had nowhere near as many as the aggressor (think medieval France or Britain vs. little island with a few thousand semi-trained militia)

Comment: The last part sounds kind of like America post WWII

Answer (score 0):

Resumption of internal warfare (assuming it had actually stopped). Almost every man and in some cases woman is already a warrior of sorts. No need for external forces to make that happen.

This scenario has been played out many times in the Pacific. Isolated islands never have enough resources for expanding populations. Control of resources is the underpinning of these societies and all males train for war as a matter of course. In rare instances the inhabitants will come together to fight an external aggressor. But usually they don't, because their longstanding blood-splattered underlying feuds are more important against their neighbours.